# sequential and hereditary Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology

A space $(X, \tau)$ is said to $T_B$ if each compact subset is closed.

A space $(X, \tau)$ is said to strongly $T_B$ if each countably compact subset is closed.

A space $(X, \tau)$ is said to (strongly) $T_B$ minimal  if $(X, \tau)$ is (strongly) $T_B$ but no topology
on X which is strictly smaller than $\tau$ is (strongly) $T_B$.

**We know that:**

(1): A hereditary Lindelöf, minimal $T_B$-space is compact.

(2): A sequential, minimal $T_B$-space is compact.

(3):In Lindelöf or sequential space, a space X is $T_B$ iff it is strongly $T_B$.

> Is there relation between **sequential and hereditary Lindelöf**?
>
> Can we say **"In Lindelöf or sequential space, a space X is $T_B$ minimal iff it is strongly $T_B$ minimal"** ?

Comment: We know that all minimal $T_B$ spaces are compact.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inclusion relation between sequential and hereditary Lindelöf. Uncountable discrete space is sequential and not Lindelöf. Aren-Fort space is countable (hence hereditary Lindelöf) but not sequential.